# How many priority numbers can a patent have?

Tags: search, date-of-invention, priority

When I search patents at espacenet.com I see that some patent documents have multiple priority numbers. For example WO2010054132 has 4 priority numbers. (see bibliographic data). What does this mean? Why there is more than 1 priority number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question.  I am unaware of any limit on the number of documents on which priority may be claimed.

Sometimes a patent application claims priority to an application that itself claims priority to another patent application.

For example, an inventor could file a provisional application.  A non-provisional application could claim priority to the provisional.  Later, the inventor could file a continuation-in-part that claims priority to both the provisional and non-provisional.

Here, WO2010054132 lists the following priority documents:

12/612,355      04.11.2009      US

61/112,080      06.11.2008      US

12/612,366      04.11.2009      US

12/612,349      04.11.2009      US

It looks like the earliest claim of priority is to a U.S. provisional filed on June 11, 2008.  Three separate U.S. non-provisionals were subsequently filed on April 11, 2009.

12/612,366 appears to have been abandoned; the other non-provisionals appear to be pending.

Comment: This is correct. There is no limit. There are some examples of applications claiming priority to more than 100 prior filings.  This becomes somewhat confusing.